# How to create inherited android app?

Tags: android, inherited

I'd like to create another app from my main app, for instace 'app with ad'.
For now i created branch in my repo, change the main source as i wanted and .. what's now?
If i build the new one it will be named as my 'main app'..
How to easy deal it?

Please help.

Comment: Typically you want to create 2 versions of same app, one with ads and another without ads???

Comment: yup, the differences between two code versions are little (only AdView added to one Activity? roughly speaking..)
But project properties is the main problem, i think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Move common business logic into [an Android library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).

Step #2: Have each flavor of your app ("main app" and "app with ad") reference the common code and resources from the Android library project.

Comment: It's interesting concept, but does it mean i need to have 3 repos?
Like, one for common libs, one for 'main' app and one for 'app with ad'?

Comment: @xliiv: What are you considering a "repo" to be?

Comment: @xliiv: That did not clarify things very much. If you are referring to a version control (e.g., git) repository, no, they can all be in one. For example, I publish a variety of open source components as Android library projects, with a `demo/` sub-project in the same repository.

Comment: could You reference an open source project as an example to clarify?

Comment: I saw the project and I understand the part of project tree (with libs in src and apps using the libs in demo directory.. ). But how do You build|run it? I'm eclipse guy and usually i just click "Run as > Android application", how to deal it with Your structure?

Comment: @xliiv: I click "Run as > Android application", the same as anyone else... but only on the `demo/` project. I have both the top-level and the `demo/` project in my Eclipse workspace.